# Play -->Stop-->Play-->Stop audio in touch

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I made a poject where two audio play using touch with the two different textview.
Here is a simple code for one textview

```
 tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)   
   {  
       if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)  
       {  
           if( v == findViewById( R.id.CustomFontText ))
           {


               if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                   mp.stop();
               }
               else
               {
                   mp.start();
               }


               if (mp1 != null && mp1.isPlaying()) {
                   mp1.pause();
               }
                mp.start();


       }  

   }
    return false;  
   }
```

Here `mp` and`mp1` are two media player. `tv=textview` .When `tv` touch `mp` play. and when `tv` touch again it stop,,,and after stopping if i touch again `tv` it does not play the audio again.But i want to make it in every touch this within this process....`Play -->Stop-->Play-->Stop....continuous`...Where i need to fix it or implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take off this chunk of code.....

```
if (mp1 != null && mp1.isPlaying()) {
               mp1.pause();
           }
            mp.start();
```

Then Every time before starting mp, release the previous one and setDataSource to Music player object, prepare it...

Chnage your code like this...

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
               mp.stop();
           }
           else
           {
               mp.release(); // this will bring mp to idle state
               mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH + File.separator + songs.get(position));
               mp.prepare();
               mp.start();
           }
```

I think now it wil work for sure...

Comment: I play the audio from raw file,,,how can i set the path of ` mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH + File.separator + songs.get(position)) ` it?

Comment: Hei...Would you please help to definr the path for raw folder?I got one.`  mp.setDataSource(appContext, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.name/raw/song"));`But the appContext show erro :(

Comment: i'm not sure... i think it plays only .mp3 file, setData from your memory card Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() this will point u to memory card root.. from there u choose ur directory or file

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) of the `MediaPlayer`.

Please note:

> Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until [`prepare()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare%28%29) or [`prepareAsync()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync%28%29) are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the *Prepared* state again.

You also seem to have a bug in your code that you call `mp.start()` twice, and `mp1.start()` is never called.

Comment: Got it...:(...If it stop it will never play again....have you any other way to do it without stopping?

Comment: If your intention is to start from the beginning every time after you stop it. `stop()` is the only way. You could, however, call `prepare()` immediately after the `stop()` so that the media is ready for playing on next touch.